# Why relative path is used in entry point and absolute path in output property of webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, relative-path, absolute-path

Recently started learning how to config react with Webpack module bundler. Below code is a simple code that I have configured till now. I have taken this code from the official documentation of [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/#output).

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

I understood that the entry point is the point where the webpack looks to start the bundling process and the output tells where to emit the bundled file that webpack creates.

But here I am getting confused why we need to have a relative path in the entry path and an absolute path in the output path?

I tried to search this information from official documentation but I didn't found any reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary for the *entry path* to be relative. It can be an absolute path too, because what's happening under the hood is a [custom join operation](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/main/lib/util/path.js#L145):

```js
const join = (rootPath, request) => {
    if (!request) return normalize(rootPath);
    const requestType = getType(request);
    switch (requestType) {
        case PathType.AbsolutePosix:
            return posixNormalize(request);
        case PathType.AbsoluteWin:
            return winNormalize(request);
    }
    switch (getType(rootPath)) {
        case PathType.Normal:
        case PathType.Relative:
        case PathType.AbsolutePosix:
            return posixNormalize(`${rootPath}/${request}`);
        case PathType.AbsoluteWin:
            return winNormalize(`${rootPath}\\${request}`);
    }
    /* ... */
};
```

So, if both `rootPath` and `request` are absolute, then the normalized version of the `request` will be returned. The normalization is achieved through the Node.js' `normalize` function(which also depends on the environment, but it fulfills the same purpose).

From [`path.normalize` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_path):

> The path.normalize() method normalizes the given path, resolving '..' and '.' segments.

However, if the `request` is not absolute, then obviously it is relative and the result of the join operation will be the resulted path after normalizing the combination of `rootPath` and `request`.

Let's now clarify what `rootPath` and `request` are. By default, the `rootPath` points to the current working directory, because it refers to the the **default value** of `options.context`, which is [`process.cwd()`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/lib/config/defaults.js#L119). So, `rootPath` refers to the current working directory.
On the other hand, concisely, `request` refers to the path you provided to the `entry` option in your snippet.

Maybe an example will clarify this. Let's assume I have a repo called `understanding-webpack`(I actually have one, [here](https://github.com/Andrei0872/understanding-webpack)). If you clone that, the `rootPath` will point, by default, to `home/user/Documents/understanding-webpack`. If the `entry`'s value is `src/foo.js`, then the **normalized path** will be `home/user/Documents/understanding-webpack/src/foo.js`.

But, as already mentioned, the `entry`'s value can also be an **absolute path**. You can provide an absolute path like this:

```js
const config = {
  /* ... */
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  /* ... */
}
```

and now, as we've seen, the normalized version of the `request` will be returned(i.e `path.join(__dirname, 'src')`).

Providing an absolute path can be useful when the directory structure is not a common one, like

```
- src
  - index.js
- webpack.config.js
```

For example, in [the repo I was referring to earlier](https://github.com/Andrei0872/understanding-webpack), the webpack config files are within the `examples` directory. So, each `entry` value will be absolute, otherwise the resulting path will always be `/home/user/Documents/understanding-webpack/src/index.js`. This is not desired, since the `examples` part does not exist.

---

The *join operation* takes place [here](https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/blob/main/lib/JoinRequestPlugin.js#L30), in the `JoinRequestPlugin`.